# fouriernc and bold problems

Tags: fonts

I use the package `fouriernc` a lot in my documents but after a recent update to my database I can't use `\bf` or `\bfseries` or `\textbf` with this font.

For instance, this isn't compilable:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}


\begin{document}
    \textbf{hello world}
\end{document}
```

Anyone else with this problem?

I can compile using XeLaTeX but PDFLaTeX doesn't produce a valid PDF, and the XeLaTeX compilation takes longer than usual.

**Result from running the compilation on a command line:**

```
> C:\latexExp>pdflatex.exe -synctex=1 -shell-escape -enable-write18
> -interaction=nonstopmode latexExp.tex pdflatex: security risk: running with elevated privileges This is pdfTeX, Version
> 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (MiKTeX 20.6 NEXT) entering extended mode (latexExp.tex LaTeX2e <2020-02-02> patch level 5 L3 programming layer
> <2020-07-17> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\article.cls"
> Document Class: article 2019/12/20 v1.4l Standard LaTeX document class
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\size10.clo"))
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\inputenc.sty")
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fouriernc\fouriernc.sty"
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fourier\fourier.sty"
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/generic/iftex\iftex.sty")
> ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\fontenc.sty" ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fourier\t1futs.fd")) ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/base\textcomp.sty") ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fourier\fourier-orns.sty"))) ("C:\Program
> Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/l3backend\l3backend-pdfmode.def")
> (latexExp.aux) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX
> 2.9\tex/latex/fouriernc\fmlfncmi.fd") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fouriernc\fmsfncm.fd") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fourier\fmxfutm.fd") ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex/latex/fouriernc\t1fnc.fd") [1 Sorry, but pdflatex.exe did not succeed.
> 
> The log file hopefully contains the information to get MiKTeX going
> again:
```

Comment: works fine for me. Which texsystem are you using?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I'm using MiKTeX (updated packages today) and TeXstudio.

Comment: run on a command line to get a better error message.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I've added the result of the compilation but, honestly, I don't know what to look for.

I've also deleted the package and reinstalled it with no better outcome. 

Don't know if I should reinstall MiKTeX all together...

Comment: hm. Try to refresh the font map files (menu tasks in the console). And don't get into the habit to use --shell-escape all the time.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer I did the refresh but the error persisted, but still, thank you very much! I ended up reinstalling MiKTeX and it seems to work now. As for the shell-escape, is it dangerous? Or is there another reason for your warning? I use GNUplot a lot and I'm kind of lazy removing the option...